# AngularJS - Cannot find directive template in script tag when unit testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, fine-uploader

I have a directive that wraps Widen's Fine Uploader utility. Functionally, it does everything I want it to, but I am now having problems writing unit tests for it.

Fine Uploader uses a template that it looks for in a script tag with the id 'qq-template'. I have placed this in a template file that is referenced in the templateUrl property of the object returned by the directive.

I have configured Grunt to run the html2js preprocessor on this file and store the code in the $templateCache. I am including the template file in the unit test in a beforeEach call.

When I run the test, I get the error:

"Cannot find template script at ID 'qq-template'!"

I have no problems when using this directive in my application. Obviously there is something that I don't understand about how templates are used. Can anybody help?

The directive:

```
angular.module('ai.upload').directive('fineUploader', function($compile) {
    return {
        replace: false,
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            validation: '@',
            uploadServer:'@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'source/shared/upload/partials/fine-uploader-template.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) { ... }
}
```

The template file:

```
<script type="text/template" id="qq-template">
<div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader">
    <div id="totalProgress" class="progress progress-striped active hide">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector uploader-drop-zone">
        <span class="drop-zone-text" ng-bind="dropZoneText"></span>
        <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list">
            <li class="file-container hide">
                <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector progress">
                    <div class="qq-progress-bar-selector progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="file-info">
                    <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
                    <img class="qq-thumbnail-selector" qq-max-size="50" qq-server-scale>
                    <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                    <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                </div>
                <button class="qq-upload-cancel-selector btn btn-small btn-warning hide" href="#">Cancel</button>
                <button class="qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry btn btn-small hide" href="#">Retry</button>
                <button class="qq-upload-delete-selector btn btn-small btn-danger hide" href="#">Delete</button>
                <span class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="qq-upload-button-selector ai-button-default button-separator select-button">
            <div ng-bind="uploadButtonText"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
        <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

The unit test:

```
describe('aiFineUploader', function() {
var element;
var scope;

beforeEach(module('ai.upload'));
beforeEach(module('source/shared/upload/partials/fine-uploader-template.html'));

beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope;

    scope.validation = {
        fileExtensions: 'xml',
        sizeLimit : '100000000',
        acceptFiles: ['text/xml']
    };

    var html =
        ' <div fine-uploader' +
        ' validation = "{{validation}}"' +
        ' upload-server="mockServer"';

    element = angular.element(html);
    $compile(element)(scope);
    $rootScope.$digest();
}));
```

Comment: The `qq-template` script tag containing your template must be available/selectable in the DOM by the time a Fine Uploader instance is created by your test/code.  The error message suggests that the order of events does not follow this requirement.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I'm trying to do exactly the same thing but can't get the tests to work... Been banging my head against the wall about it for quite a while now.

Comment: @mylescc did you see the answer the OP included?

Comment: @RayNicholus sorry what do you mean by OP?

Comment: @mylescc The original poster, the question-asker.

Comment: @RayNicholus Ah thats what it means! So his solution still didn't work for me. I've made a temporary fix that stops the calling of fineuploader in the directive so I can test all the other functions I want to test, so I think thats fine for now. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Debug your site in a chrome if you can and check the source. See if there is a folder path with different casing for your html files

I had a crazy issue where my grunt/karma setup would load the html into a path like this (app/src/Templates/my.html)
but my $templateCache was looking for (app/src/templates/my.html)

the problem was a casing issues  /Templates vs /templates

Also in your test, even though the html gets loaded you may have to manually populate the template cache, which is what I had to do because of the path issue

**EDIT: try using moduleName**

Make sure you are using the ngHtml2js pre-processor

In your karma config file you could try using the moduleName option

```
ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
    moduleName: 'myModule'
}
```

**If you are using require.js**

I am using require in my project and was having an issue where it wasn't filling my $templateCache. Looking at what the html2js pre-processor was doing i modified the template
to wrap an object around name and html

```
TEMPLATE = '(function() {\n' +
'  define([], function(){\n' +
'      return { name: \'%s\', html: \'%s\' };    \n' +
'  });\n' +
'}());\n';
```

in my test i just added the myHtml.html.js file as a dependency in my test

```
define(['myHtml.html'], function (myHtml) {

    describe('Test', function () {

        it('should...', inject(function ($injector, $rootScope, $controller, $compile, $templateCache) {

            var $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
            $httpBackend.whenGET('/' + myHtml.name).respond(myHtml.html);
            var $scope = $rootScope.$new(); 
            var element = $compile('<div my-directive></div>')($scope);
            $scope.$digest();
            $httpBackend.flush();

            expect(element
        }

    }));
}
```

just some thoughts

Comment: Thank you for your input Mark. I don't think that this is the problem that I am experiencing though. I can see that the $templateCache does contain the template by calling console.log($templateCache.get('source/shared/upload/partials/fine-uploader-template.html')).

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem was to manually append the element to the document body in the beforeEach block using angular.element(). It is now available when FineUploader looks for it. The block now looks like:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $templateCache) {
    scope = $rootScope;

    scope.validation = {
        fileExtensions: 'xml',
        sizeLimit : '100000000',
        acceptFiles: ['text/xml']
    };

    scope.onUploadComplete = function(){
        return 'onUploadComplete called';
    }

    scope.updateFileStatus = function(){
        return 'updateFileStatus called';
    }

    var html =
        ' <div fine-uploader' +
        ' validation = "{{validation}}"' +
        ' upload-server="mockServer"'+
        ' authentication-token="123"'+
        ' on-submit-file="onSubmitFile(file)"'+
        ' update-file-status="updateFileStatus(file)"'+
        ' on-upload-complete="onUploadComplete(response, file)">'+
        '</div>';

    element = angular.element(html);
    $compile(element)(scope);
    angular.element(document.body).append(element);
    scope.$digest();
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and the answer by ***cormacb*** provided the hint I needed (big THANK YOU to ***cormacb***!).

In my working approach, in `beforeEach` I define the `<script type="text/template" id="qq-template">` in an html variable text-string and then append that html to the `document.body` first. Then, I create the fine-uploader `<div>`, compile it, and digest it -- at which point the `qq-template` is available.

```
var html =
        '<script type="text/template" id="qq-template">' +
        '    <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader qq-gallery" ng-attr-qq-drop-area-text="{{ dropZoneText }}">' +
        '        <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container">' +
// ...
        '        </div>' +
        '    </div>' +
        '</script>';

angular.element(document.body).append(html);

var element = angular.element('<div fine-uploader></div>');
var compiledElement = _compile(element)(_scope);
_scope.$digest();
```

This approach uses a simple html/text definition for the `qq-template` and does not require the use of any html2js pre-processor-izing as used in the other answers here.

Hope this helps someone else. Thanks SO community for all the great answers!